# Openapi generator maven plugin generate classes with missing symbol

Tags: spring-boot, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I use `openapi-generator-maven-plugin` to generate classes from openapi yml files but in some of them I get this errors:

`Cannot find symbol symbol:   method requiredMode() location: @interface io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema`

I checked in `io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema` and method requiredMode() is really missing.

Below my pom file:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.maglione</groupId>
<artifactId>contactsapi</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>contactsapi</name>
<description>Demo project </description>
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <openapi-generator.version>6.6.0</openapi-generator.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind-nullable</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${openapi-generator.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <inputSpec>
                             ${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/contactsapi.yml
                        </inputSpec>
                        <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                        <apiPackage>com.maglione.contactsapi.api</apiPackage>
                        <modelPackage>com.maglione.contactsapi.model</modelPackage>
                        <supportingFilesToGenerate>
                            ApiUtil.java
                        </supportingFilesToGenerate>
                        <configOptions>
                            <delegatePattern>true</delegatePattern>
                            <useSpringBoot3>true</useSpringBoot3>

                        </configOptions>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I tried to search online for possible bug but did not find anything

Comment: What version of the `swagger-annotations` library does the generated code use? `requiredMode` [exists](https://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/v2.2.7/apidocs/io/swagger/v3/oas/annotations/media/Schema.html#required--) in v. 2.2.5+.

Comment: I had the same error message running it in IntelliJ idea with the dependency `springdoc-openapi-ui:jar:1.7.0` in the pom. Somehow an older version of `swagger-annotations` was available on the classpath of IntelliJ. I deleted the `swagger-annotations`folder in the local maven repo and then it worked.

Answer (score 5):

As *Helen* mentioned, `requiredMode()` exists only in newer versions of `swagger-annotations`.
To check what version your project is using, run `mvn dependency:tree`. You'll find that `swagger-annotations` version 2.1.2 is used, as transitively included via `springfox-swagger2`.

If you remove the `supportingFilesToGenerate` section from your pom.xml, openapi-generator will create a file `.target/generated-sources/openapi/pom.xml` that tells you the intended dependencies to be used with the generated code. In your case, these dependencies include `io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-core-jakarta:jar:2.2.7`, transitively included via `org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:jar:2.0.2`.

To fix your build, you need to include the newer swagger dependency. And you also need to exclude the old swagger dependency, so that maven knows it has to use the annotations from the new dependency and cannot use the annotations from the old dependency.

---

**So to fix your problem, replace this:**

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

**by this:**

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
                    <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-core-jakarta</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.7</version>
        </dependency>
```